# multiple input file upload using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have multiple input fields of type file generated using php foreach loop.
Below is a snippet html form generated

```
    <input name="userImage" id="a1Cym4V" type="file" />
    <button type="button" onclick="upload_proof('a1Cym4V')">Upload</button>

    <input name="userImage" id="pe7h6Cx" type="file" />
    <button type="button" onclick="upload_proof('pe7h6Cx')">Upload</button>

    <input name="userImage" id="L9iCaxV" type="file" />
    <button type="button" onclick="upload_proof('L9iCaxV')">Upload</button>
```

If i upload an image using the first input form, it works fine, all others will return empty value even when a file is selected.
 
This is the javascript code i use to process the file upload via ajax.

```
function upload_prooff(id){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    formData.append('id', id);
    formData.append('upload_proof', '1');
    $.ajax({
        url: "convert.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The `data` contains `var_dump($_FILES)` from the server.
What is the best approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Assuming you have a `form` element just provide it to the constructor: `new FormData($('#yourForm')[0]);`. Then you can upload via AJAX as you are.

Comment: I do not understand the question very well. Could explain further? Also, I can see that the `id` of your `<button>` has a typo saying "submitt" with two "t"s. Also, I see you are using single quotes two times in a row at the `onclick` without any escape character. Is that syntactically correct?

Comment: @DimitrisDamilos those are typos. I'm echoing raw php values into the javascript function that's why i used the single quotes.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan i'll try that right away thank you

Comment: Then, please give us your PHP code and an actual HTML generated output, please, so we can help you better.

Comment: i'll include it right now

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i've tried your suggestion and it's still not working.